# JAVA_HOME is not set. (RuntimeError) while installing rjb gem for ruby in WSL

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, windows-subsystem-for-linux, java-home

I am  trying to install the gem rjb and I have come across this error

`extconf.rb:53:in <main>': JAVA_HOME is not set. (RuntimeError)`.

The following is the entire error log.

```
$sudo gem install rjb -v '1.4.9' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
[sudo] password for santoshpavan:
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rjb:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rjb-1.4.9/ext
/usr/bin/ruby2.5 -r ./siteconf20200411-19244-10jhs3k.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.5
extconf.rb:53:in `<main>': JAVA_HOME is not set. (RuntimeError)

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/rjb-1.4.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/rjb-1.4.9/gem_make.out
```

I tried the answer that is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53574705/7271176).

When I printed the `env` I can see the `JAVA_HOME` path mentioned, as below.

```
santoshpavan@DESKTOP-ISVIQCL:/mnt/c/code/expertiza$ env
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
HOSTTYPE=x86_64
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
LANG=C.UTF-8
OLDPWD=/mnt/c
WSL_DISTRO_NAME=Ubuntu-18.04
JAVA_HOME=/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-10.0.2
S_COLORS=auto
USER=santoshpavan
RBENV_SHELL=bash
PWD=/mnt/c/code/expertiza
HOME=/home/santoshpavan
NAME=DESKTOP-ISVIQCL
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
SHLVL=1
LOGNAME=santoshpavan
PATH=/home/santoshpavan/.yarn/bin:/home/santoshpavan/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:/home/santoshpavan/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/santoshpavan/.rbenv/shims:/home/santoshpavan/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_2020.1804.7.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/Python37/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Python37/:/mnt/c/Python27/:/mnt/c/Python27/Scripts:/mnt/c/Users/santo/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Users/santo/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.1/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.1/libnvvp:/mnt/c/app/santo/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-10.0.2/bin:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/Nsight Compute 2019.4.0/:/mnt/c/Apache/apache-zookeeper-3.5.6-bin/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-10.0.2/bin:/mnt/c/Spark/spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/PostgreSQL/12/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/PostgreSQL/12/lib:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon/:/mnt/c/Users/santo/.cargo/bin:/mnt/c/Ruby27-x64/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/usr/local/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System3:/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.4/bin:/snap/bin
WSLENV=JAVA_HOME/p
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
_=/usr/bin/env
```

I do no understand the issue here as `JAVA_HOME` is present in the environment variables with the WSLENV.

**Note**:

Earlier, when I had the same error, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53574705/7271176) helped. But the `javac` was still was not being detected. So, I installed java in wsl using `$ sudo apt install default-jdk`. And, after that this issue has happened.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** In WSL, you must use `javac.exe` since it is a Windows binary. Simply typing `javac` will not work, even if the path is set up correctly. If that doesn't work, try adding `../bin` to the end of your `JAVA_HOME` variable.

### Using Windows Binaries & Environment Variables in WSL

If you have JavaSDK installed on Windows, you **do not** need to install Linux binaries. Simply ensure that they are properly linked so WSL knows where to find the SDK.

Also, when calling a Windows binary from WSL, you cannot type `javac`, you must type `javac.exe` so WSL knows we're looking in the Windows file system.

### Ensure Java for Windows works

Open PowerShell or cmd.exe from any directory and type `java --version`

You should get a list of JRK info:

```sh
    openjdk 11.0.4 2019-07-16 LTS
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.4.11.1 (build 11.0.4+11-LTS)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.4.11.1 (build 11.0.4+11-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Your version might be different, **the important part is that the system knows where to find Java**. If you get an error, ensure your Windows Environment variables are set correctly:

- JAVA_HOME as an Environment Variable, and
- JAVA_HOME/bin as a Path variable.

### Setting Variable in WSL

The best place to put the next lines of code are in your `.bashrc` file (I have mine right before sourcing my aliases & functions), but if you are running multiple users or simply prefer `./bash_profile` or `/etc/profile` put it there.

```sh
    # Shared environment variables
    export JAVA_HOME=/mnt/d/Java/jdk11.0.4_10
```

While we're at it, add any other Environment Variables you will need in your development setup.

I have my WSL, Java, and all my other dev tools set up on my second HDD which is not a system drive, ensure that your location matches your JAVA_HOME path in Windows.

> If JavaSDK is located at: `C:\Java\jdk8.0`
> The corresponding WSL mount point is: `/mnt/c/Java/jdk8.0`

### Executing

**Important:** Use `java.exe <args>` in WSL instead of `java <args>`

Say you just wrote `CompareTwoStrings.class` and want to compile and run it using the Windows binaries. You can do it from a Windows shell or WSL.

**From Windows Shell:**

```
    javac GetStringLength.java
    java GetStringLength
```

**From WSL:**

```
    javac.exe GetStringLength.java
    java.exe GetStringLength
```

> Using `java <args>` in WSL will result in a `Command 'java' not found` error. That is because running windows binaries from within WSL **requires that the `.exe` extension is used** in the command.

#### Simplicity

We don't want to install a second copy of Java specific to WSL and waste that precious disk space, so we're going to call the Windows binary from the WSL shell. This is a great benefit of WSL (WSL1 in particular) in that it can interact (almost) flawlessly with the Windows File System.

> **NOTE:** In order to run a program, it must either be a `Path` variable, or be run from within it's containing folder.

Hopefully that works as easily for you as it did for me. Just remember to use the correct command depending on what OS binary you're running. This took me about 10 minutes to get set up, and has been a lifesaver for cross-compiling and general ease-of-use.