# Maven on WSL2 can't see JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, maven, windows-10, wsl-2

I have JDK 11 and Maven 3.8.1 installed on my Windows 10 machine. Took care that install paths don't have spaces.

Made the value of `JAVA_HOME` visible inside the Ubuntu shell following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53574705/91933). Then I restarted the Ubuntu shell.

Here are the outputs from inside an Ubuntu shell on Windows Terminal:

```
user@computer:/path$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.10+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.10+9, mixed mode)

user@computer:/path$ env | grep JAVA
JAVA_HOME=/mnt/c/AdoptOpenJDK/jdk-11-hotspot

user@computer:/path$ mvn -v
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

So although the value of `JAVA_HOME` is visible inside the Ubuntu shell, somehow `mvn` can't see it. How do I fix this?

Maven run from `cmd` gives this output:

```
C:\path>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: C:\Maven\bin\..
Java version: 11.0.10, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK, runtime: C:\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11-hotspot
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Versions:

- Windows 10 version 2004 (OS Build 19041.1110)
- Java 11.0.10
- Maven 3.8.1
- WSL2
- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (via WSL2)

Comment: Just a vague idea, but do you by any chance have `<fork>true</fork>` in your pom? If so, try making that `false` and see what happens

Comment: There is no pom, no project. I was just trying to see that Maven would run correctly inside WSL2.

Comment: That's that theory out of the window then ;) Are you sure if's the *same* Maven you're running in each OS?

Comment: You probably can't run maven under WSL (in bash) with a Windows JDK. You could try a Linux JDK instead.

Comment: >Maven home: C:\Maven\bin\..< seems a little strange. What happens when you do this? `export MAVEN_HOME=/mnt/c/Maven;mvn -v`

Comment: @g00se Still the same error.

Comment: @JornVernee if we're supposed to run the Windows JDK in WSL2, shouldn't we be running the Windows Maven as well?

Comment: If you want to force running maven with the Windows JDK, you can't invoke `mvn` from `bash`. But you can run from `cmd` with e.g.: `$ cmd.exe /C "mvn --version"`

Comment: Maybe try exporting both variables before invoking `mvn` then?

Comment: I am trying to use Quarkus, which involves using Docker, which involves running code from inside the WSL2 filesystem. Shouldn't I be running Maven from inside WSL2 as well?

Comment: @g00se I tried setting 1st `MAVEN_HOME` & then `M2_HOME`, but neither worked. The values were visible in `wsl`, but Maven still wouldn't work.

Comment: Em… Are you sure you installed a JDK and not a JRE? What does `javac -version` tells?

Comment: @Auktis Yes, it's definitely JDK. `java -version` says `javac 11.0.10`.

Comment: @markvgti Maybe the best is to install Maven and Java on Ubuntu. That should work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up and simply installed JDK 11 & Maven 3.8.1 inside WSL2 using SDKMAN.

Not an ideal solution, but didn't feel like spending more time on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't disagree with your solution to use the Linux versions of Java and Maven inside WSL, but I do think I see why your example in the original question was failing.

The problem appears to be that you are using the Windows versions of Java/Maven, BUT your JAVA_HOME from inside WSL is using the "Linux form" of the path (`/mnt/c/AdoptOpenJDK/jdk-11-hotspot`).

Maven is complaining, because since it is running under Windows, it doesn't understand that path.  It needs to see `C:\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11-hotspot`.

I believe this is because the answer you linked to said to use `setx WSLENV "JAVA_HOME/p"`.  The `/p` is forcing the translation from the Windows path to the WSL/Linux mapping, which you *don't* want in this case.

Also, be sure to restart the Terminal from which you launch WSL so that it can pick up the new environment variables.

Comment: this is not it. i tried using the windows path and i still get the same error